# Highcharts using AngularJS, NodeJS and Mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, highcharts, mongoose

I am beginner on Javascript world. I am trying to use high charts (www.highcharts.com) for pia charts on AngularJS. I have below example which works fine but below example has "ideas" array static but I wanted to do this from MongoDB rather than static value. I am not sure what needs to be done here to make this dynamic. I have tried few stuffs and I am able to get data from Mongo on simple NodeJS program but I am not sure how do I integrate that with AngularJS? How do I replace "$scope.ideas" value with data that I am getting on my NodeJS code?

Please help me as I am totally confuse with next step here. I have spent lot of time to find out details and do few stuffs but no luck.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="hc-pie" items="limitedIdeas"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function MyCtrl($scope, limitToFilter) {
  $scope.ideas = [
    ['ideas1', 1],
    ['ideas2', 8],
    ['ideas3', 5]
  ];

  $scope.limitedIdeas = limitToFilter($scope.ideas, 3);
}

angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('hcPie', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      items: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      console.log(2);

    },
    template: '<div id="container" style="margin: 0 auto">not working</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(3);
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          plotBackgroundColor: null,
          plotBorderWidth: null,
          plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
          percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              color: '#000000',
              connectorColor: '#000000',
              formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.percentage + ' %';
              }
            }
          }
        },
        series: [{
          type: 'pie',
          name: 'Browser share',
          data: scope.items
        }]
      });
      scope.$watch("items", function (newValue) {
        chart.series[0].setData(newValue, true);
      }, true);

    }
  }
});

</script>
```

Simple node find method is as below which uses mongoose as well.

```
foult.find({$and:[ {"instrument":"android"} , {"sentiments": {"$gt":0}} ]}, function(err, foult) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  androidSentimentArray = ["foult", foult.length];
  console.dir(foult);
});
```

Comment: you need to try the angular directive to render the hightchart https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng which will reduce most you directive work of rendering graph..

Comment: @PankajParkar, Thank you for answering here but my question is, how do I integrate separate node code and Angular code. Node code gets me data from Mongo and Angular displays it but I don't know how do I pass foult.find method response to $scope.ideas array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a service (singleton) or factory to make an http request and get/post the data to the node server and you'll inject the service/factory in your controller.

```
angular.module('').controller('myController', function(ideasService) {
    ideasService.getIdeas()
        .then(function(result) {
            //Apply returned data to view
            $scope.ideas = result.data;
         });
});

angular.module('')
    .service('ideasService', function($http) {
        this.getIdeas = function() {
            //returns promise
            return $http.get('url')
                      .then(function(response) {
                           console.log(response.data);
                       });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but should I connect to MongoDB from service? Basically where should I foult.find method which I have shown above which gets me the data that I am looking for? is that part of code will go under "//return promise" comment that you have wrote? Sorry If I am asking some stupid questions but I am beginner on this so not much aware.

Comment: That find code should be running on the node server and your angular code is running on the client. You will need to set up a node server with express to have routes that you can call to return the data.

Here is a fiddle that shows the basic layout of an express app
https://jsfiddle.net/t2gcgdvq/

You'll need to npm install express on your project

Comment: Yes. I was looking into expressjs with node and Angular but got confused. I saw famous todo example which returns getTodo list (/api/todos URI). This /api/todos URI will return the list of todo but in my case, I need to return array of array for ideas right? Sorry I am taking this into different direction now but my end goal is the have that  $scope.ideas dynamically populated from MongoDB.

Comment: Here is a revised version that gives a basic example with mongodb https://jsfiddle.net/t2gcgdvq/1/ so when you call getIdeas it will make an api to the node server that will return a json array of documents and then you'll be able to access them like I showed in the controller.

Comment: OK. Thank you for this. Let me try making this working with express and I will let you know if I face any issues on this.

Comment: I have tried doing what you suggested here and I am getting error as TypeError: ideas.find(...).toArray is not a function. this is because I am using Mongoose and mongoose doesn't support toArray method but wondering what can be done here if I want to achieve similar using mongoose? Can I just convert "docs" from "     response.json(docs);"  into array and than send it as response?

Comment: Yes .json will convert objects into json and send it in the response.

Comment: No problem glad I could help.